# joomla 1.6 how to include modules in page which is not under any menus

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions

I have to update an existing Joomla site(1.6), I have to add some contents on the home page ( news flash, contents from a particular category), I created this and now I want to know how can I include a few modules in the details page.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Joomla syntax, `{loadposition modulePosition}` or you can use [ModulesAnywhere](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere), which offers more custom options.

Comment: +1 for ModulesAnywhere - great component!  I think the OP may need to get a better handle on how Joomla handles modules anyway - I think the default addition of modules to pages is what he's after, but great suggestions.